# Django: Get queryset of nested objects in Retrieve API View

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, djongo

I'm creating a Django application with django-rest-framework and using djongo to connect to MongoDB. I have a nested model as such:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_code = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        blank=False,
        unique=True
    )

    users = models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container=User
    )

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )

    user_code = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        default=hex_uuid,
        editable=False
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I'm attempting to set up a view to retrieve a User at the following URL:

```
urlpatterns = {
    url(r'^user/(?P<group_code>[\w]+)/(?P<user_code>[\w]+)/$',
        UserDetail.as_view(), name='user-detail')
}
```

Essentially, I want the view to display just the User's information instead of the Group's information. This didn't work, but is what I attempted:

```
class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserFullSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Group.objects.get(team_code=self.kwargs['group_code']).users

    lookup_field = 'user_code'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'user_code'
```

However, `users` in this case is a normal list instead of a QuerySet. Therefore, the `lookup_field` attribute is not working correctly. Any thoughts on how to access the nested list `users` of type User as a QuerySet so that this view can work properly? Or am I approaching this in an incorrect way?